# Spark shuffle blocks replication

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to know if it's possible to define replication logic to shuffle blocks without using persist action.
Use case is having complex sql with multiple joins which requires a big amount of shuffles which is saved on worker machines (with splill), loosing a machine might require stage retries (using dag) which is very expansive and might not always work.

Can it be done using configuration or by inheriting from some class in spark context.

Version Spark 2.3

Comment: Could you explain the context? What would be the possible application?

Comment: @user10465355 edited question

Comment: Thanks. Have you considered using shuffle service? It doesn't satisfy the criteria, but decouples the shuffle layer and storage of the shuffle files, from the executor - therefore failure of the latter one is not critical.

Comment: @user10465355 i did consider but uses a big amount of storage space, which is very expansive when running under AWS and this is again not required for all types of applications

Comment: @user10465355 also if a machine is killed shuffle service and all data is anyway gone

Comment: any way of replication shuffle data?